# How do you set the height of a view programmatically?

Tags: android, view

I have 2 views - a container view, and a gauge view. I want to programmatically change the height of the gauge view. The problem is that when I get the height of the container view - it always comes back as 2.0 - even though the height is full-screen!

```
    int fullHeight = containerView.getLayoutParams().height;
    Number height = fullHeight * (thisTank.getTankTotalVolume().doubleValue()/thisTank.getTankMaxVolume().doubleValue());
    Number width = gaugeView.getWidth();
    //gaugeView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width.intValue(), height.intValue()));
    gaugeView.getLayoutParams().height = height.intValue() * fullHeight;
    gaugeView.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you set the view's height to `WRAP_CONTENT` or `MATCH_PARENT` in `XML`,  the `containerView.getLayoutParams().height` should be equals to 2, its a default value...!

You have to two options,

> - First, you can defined a fix value in the XML file
> - Second, and recommended, you can use a tree observer for this purpose. Please see the below code...!

```
final View layout = (View)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```